# Convert a stringfied list to python list and get values

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, list

I'm quite new to AWS. I have two lambdas, the first one makes a query to RDS and receive a result like
**[('asdzxc', '12345-0', 123), ('asdzxc', '67890-0', 456)]**, and the second invokes the first and takes the query. The problem is that the query is received as string:
**"[('asdzxc', '12345-0', 123), ('asdzxc', '67890-0', 456)]"**. And I need iterate and take values to use them in another output. But when I iterate, it shows one char per line. I been reading some docs and tried using `json.loads()`, `list()`, `tuple()`, `ast.literal_eval`. But I still get the same.

Here's a fragment of the first lambda:

```py
query = select_from_bcuc(rut_crypto)
print(query)
str_data = json.dumps(str(query))
return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'request_id': request_id,
        'body': str_data,
        'msg': 'Hello from extractData!!!'
    }

> output: [('asdzxc', '12345-0', 123), ('asdzxc', '67890-0', 456)]
```

And the second lambda:

```py
obj = extractData(rut)
    if obj:
        print('Getting data.')
        print(obj['body'])
        p = json.loads(obj['body'])
        print(p)

> output: "[('asdzxc', '12345-0', 123), ('asdzxc', '67890-0', 456)]"
```

Comment: @Marcin sorry for the late anwser, finally i had to concatenate a key in the beginning and turn it into dictionary and then made a lot of code that might not be appropiate, in a pythonic way. Your solution works only if both, select query and extract data are in the same lambda. But still I'll mark it a the answer for anyone else who had a similar problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
import ast
s="[('asdzxc', '12345-0', 123), ('asdzxc', '67890-0', 456)]"
a_list = ast.literal_eval(s)
print(type(a_list), a_list)
```

gives:

```
<class 'list'> [('asdzxc', '12345-0', 123), ('asdzxc', '67890-0', 456)]
```

Comment: this converts to list, however it still gives char per line when iterating.

Comment: @anubiros_theron You have to double check what you did. Its not possible to iterate over a list as string.